# How to map time(0) to TimeOnly Entity Framework SQL Server 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to use the new `TimeOnly` type of C# but when I come to do my migrations I am having the following issue. I am using SQL Server 2019 the error is.

> The property 'PassportOffice.CloseTime' is of type 'DateTime' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I'm using Entity Framework Core 6. The model is as follows.

```
public class PassportOffice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TimeOnly OpenTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TimeOnly CloseTime { get; set; }
}
```

So I've tried to make TimeOnly converter

```
public class TimeOnlyConverter : ValueConverter<TimeOnly, DateTime>
{
    public TimeOnlyConverter() : base(
       timeOnly => new DateTime(DateOnly.MinValue.Year, DateOnly.MinValue.Month, DateOnly.MinValue.Day,
            timeOnly.Hour, timeOnly.Minute, timeOnly.Second),
       dateTime => TimeOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime))
   { }
}
```

And used it in DbContext as follows

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Properties<TimeOnly>()
        .HaveConversion<TimeOnlyConverter>()
        .HaveColumnType("time(0)");
}
```

Did I made a mistake? Or is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: A SQL Server `time` data type maps directly to CLR type `TimeSpan`. Maybe that's another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework Map CLR type **TimeSpan** SQL Server type to **time**

Change the Model Definition as below

```
public class PassportOffice
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public TimeSpan OpenTime { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public TimeSpan CloseTime { get; set; }
    }
```

No Need for Converter. it will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a converter from TimeOnly to TimeSpan?

```
public class TimeOnlyConverter : ValueConverter<TimeOnly, TimeSpan>
{
    public TimeOnlyConverter() : base(
        d => d.ToTimeSpan(),
        d => TimeOnly.FromTimeSpan(d))
    { }
}
```